# Concat successive rows in pandas based on regex

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe, rows, concatenation

I have a following dataframe that contains `date` is distorted way.

```
index   Date    Particulars
0       01-12-  AVON AGRO
1       2018    NaN
2       01-12-  CASH
3       2018    NaN
4       03-12-  NEFTOut/UTBIN18337459966/LUNI
5       2018    A MARKETING/SBIN00019
6       03-12-  ANJANI TRADERS
7       2018    NaN
8       03-12-  NEFTOut/UTBIN18337484160/BIGS
9       2018    MILE PRODUCTS/UTIB000
```

but I want following output  like:

```
index   Date        Particulars
0       01-12-2018  AVON AGRO
2       01-12-2018  CASH
4       03-12-2018  NEFTOut/UTBIN18337459966/LUNIA MARKETING/SBIN00019
6       03-12-2018  ANJANI TRADERS
8       03-12-2018  NEFTOut/UTBIN18337484160/BIGSMILE PRODUCTS/UTIB000
```

I have tried with `df.apply(lambda x: x if re.search('\d{4}$', str(x)) else str(x.shift(-1)) + str(x))` but it is giving me:

```
Date           0         2018\n1       01-12-\n2         2018...
Particulars    0                                 NaN\n1      ...
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace missing values to empty string and then join inpair and pair rows by `groupby` with `join`:

```
df1 = df.fillna('').groupby(df.index // 2).agg(''.join)
print (df1)
             Date                                        Particulars
index                                                               
0      01-12-2018                                          AVON AGRO
1      01-12-2018                                               CASH
2      03-12-2018  NEFTOut/UTBIN18337459966/LUNIA MARKETING/SBIN0...
3      03-12-2018                                     ANJANI TRADERS
4      03-12-2018  NEFTOut/UTBIN18337484160/BIGSMILE PRODUCTS/UTI...
```

Or select pair and unpair by positions:

```
df1 = df.fillna('')
df1 = df1.iloc[::2].reset_index(drop=True) + df1.iloc[1::2].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
         Date                                        Particulars
0  01-12-2018                                          AVON AGRO
1  01-12-2018                                               CASH
2  03-12-2018  NEFTOut/UTBIN18337459966/LUNIA MARKETING/SBIN0...
3  03-12-2018                                     ANJANI TRADERS
4  03-12-2018  NEFTOut/UTBIN18337484160/BIGSMILE PRODUCTS/UTI...
```

Solution with regex is also possible:

```
df1 = df.fillna('')
m = df1['Date'].str.contains('\d{4}$')
df1 = df1[m.shift(-1).fillna(False)].reset_index(drop=True) + df1[m].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I like the solution with regex as it is useful to me.